# PreUpdate not triggered

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this method in my entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function preStore() {
        if ($this->getPictureFile()) {
            $newFilename = sha1(mt_rand());
            $newFilename = $newFilename . '.' . ($this->getPictureFile()->guessExtension());
            $this->setPictureFilename($newFilename);
        }
    }
```

And when persisting objects everything works just perfectly but on update the method is not triggered at all, i tested it this way:

```
/**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function preStore() { var_dump('asdasdasdadsdasdas');
        if ($this->getPictureFile()) {
            $newFilename = sha1(mt_rand());
            $newFilename = $newFilename . '.' . ($this->getPictureFile()->guessExtension());
            $this->setPictureFilename($newFilename);
        }
    }
```

And in persisting var_dump works, but when I update the object - it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 53):

A update does only occur if a entity field (watched from doctrine)  gets changed and so on the preupdate method is only called after a change.

Caution: i guess your picture file is not a doctrine column and so on not watched by doctrine. So your entity does not change for doctrine.

From [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) cookbook article

> The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks are only triggered if there is a change in one of the entity's field that are persisted. This means that, by default, if you modify only the $file property, these events will not be triggered, as the property itself is not directly persisted via Doctrine. One solution would be to use an updated field that's persisted to Doctrine, and to modify it manually when changing the file.

**EDIT**: Or you use the [Uploadable behavior](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#using-uploadable-extension) of the [doctrine extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md)

Comment: Hmmm... so if I change the doctrine column to anything, "xxx" for example - then it should work after all since the doctrine mapped filename is then changed to an auto-generated one?

Comment: @PatrikKarishch ¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡ GRACIASSSSSSSSS (THANKSSSSSSSSSS) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Amazing point on the optimization of the ORM and the @PreUpdate call -- great post

Answer (score 12):

You have to tell doctrine explicitly that your entity has lifecycle-callbacks:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class YourClass
```

further you don't need the trailing `()` in your annotations if you don't prvovide any options.

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function preStore()
```

consider using a listener/subscriber instead of lifecycle-callbacks allowing easier re-use and keeping your entity cleaner.

More information can be found in the cookbook chapter [How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

Comment: If I didn't have @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks then prepersist wouldn't work too and as I said - it works perfectly. Removing trailing () didn't change anything. I know I can do it with event listeners but I want to know why it's not working?

Comment: The trailing () are no different than if you do `new Foo()`. Annotations are just classes called in a special way. Just like with classes, you can do `new Foo` but many standards like PSR-12 say to include the parens regardless of if you have arguments so many people include them in annotations too.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, here is my solution:

add a mapped field `updatedAt` and just call `setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime())` inside of the `setter` of your `UploadedFile` this will trigger the `preUpdate-Event` for the entity

Comment: A good solution hand-in-hand with @Patrik's answer which explains why this works

Answer (score -1):

Another reason this can fail is if you have only one asterisk

Fails:
`/* @ORM\PrePersist */`

Succeeds:
`/** @ORM\PrePersist */`

Ridiculous, but there it is..